# Caps lock remap release delay

Tags: keyboard

I'm trying to remap the caps lock key of a wireless aluminum Apple keyboard and am having a delay on **release** (not activation). That is to say, if I hold down the caps lock key after remapping, it will act like the key is pressed for a short period even after I release it. The longer the key is held, the longer this behavior happens.

I'm trying to remap it to ctrl but have the same problem with cmd.

I've found a lot of posts talking about an activation delay, but this is different than my problem.

I've tried the built in remapping as well as [Seil](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html.en), and both have the same problem.

Comment: If this only happens on the caps lock key it could be because Apple has setup this key to have a lag that prevents someone from pressing it by accident, in this case perhaps there is a conflict... If you try using another key and it works fine I would suggest that it's a conflict with this behaviour Apple has added to the caps lock key

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/), or probably an alternative.

1. Disable Caps Lock in System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard > Modifier Keys
   [image: system prefs]
2. Create a Keyboard Maestro macro that is triggered by "This device key:" and set it to trigger when the Caps Lock key is released.
3. Add whatever action you want to remap it to—if I understand your question correctly, you'd want to add "Type Modifiers" and set it to Control.
   [image: keyboard maestro]